# Can Bigcommerce orders have additional details and line items properties

Tags: migration, shopify, bigcommerce, orders

Migrating from Shopify to Bigcommerce and found that orders in Shopify has line items properties and additional details that must be migrated to Bigcommerce orders through API or Apps.

Official API specification of Bigcommerce has no as such provision. Wondering if it's still possible or require different approach to store such additional details of Shopify orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a procedure you can try:

> 1. Migrate Products from Shopify to BigCommerce -. either via API or App

Shopify API: https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/products/product#index-2021-07
BigCommerce API: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/products/createproduct

> 2. Fetch Orders along with Line Items from Shopify

API: https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/orders/order#index-2021-07

> 3. Create Orders to BigCommerce and with Product's Name instead of variant IDs (Check Examples available in below API).

API: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/orders/orders/createanorder

> 4. Add additional LineItem Shopify details in BigCommerce Orders via BigCommerce v3 API.

API: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/order-transactions/metafields/createordermetafield

Note:There could be other ways to create orders in BigCommerce with exact LineItem details via API but, this process would need mapping of Shopify Variant's option IDs to BigCommerce Variant's option IDs.

Comment: Yeah, based on official API specification, order metafield is the option. How does this appear in the admin portal of orders. Alike Shopify, does that appear as the display contents?. My apology, I am about to create this logic but keen to know if the information will be displayed within each orders? Any screenshot would be helpful?

Comment: @Satty, I don't think BigCommerce allows to view meta details in BigCommerce Store, the meta fields are limited to APIs for POS solutions. However, you can still set limited additional details (like the value of size, color, ordered quantity, and price.) by appending the data in `Ordered Product Name` during order creation via the Custom Order creation process.

Comment: Yep, that's where the migration got stuck as based on BC order data display, it's annoying. Line item properties and additional details in Shopify gives a flexibility in adding additional details for display and usage. In this scenario, if still such migration needs these data to be restored in BC, will have to think some other solution.

Comment: Hey @Satty, well, would you like to try to send additional details in Order customer_message....I think these details would be visible to you in your BigCommerce store as well....wondering there could be a length limitation. Another method, could be creating hidden products with Order Line Item details products in BigCommerce (put all of them in a separate BigCommerce category), and create order with these product details. During product creation you can utilize `custom_fields`  to put additional Line Item level details :-)

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Kumar for helping. I had in parallel discussion with BC tech team and were very helpful. I concluded to architect and implement a hybrid solution based on our discussion and with them. Just wanted to get the best out of the platform.

Comment: In short, before ticking this post as accepted answer, summarising available artefacts in BC: order's custom metafield, customer notes, staff notes, product option modifiers, pick list and as and when need a bit of custom solution will suffice Shopify order migration along with product design if we need bundling of products and supporting bulk orders. Also, I'ld have opted for paid Apps for such migration but the usecase is different hence better to do yourself if time and budget allows to gain more flexibility.

Comment: Agree, let me know if any further help required from my side. Thanks, @Satty